# Does google value .com/.net/.org domains higher than new domains such as .club or .film?

Tags: seo, top-level-domains

There are many new top level domains now, such as `.club` and `.film`. Does anyone know if Google values old school `.com`, `.net` and `.org` higher than these new domains?

I'm asking because I want to make a new website and I wonder if I should get this new domain or go with old domain. I prefer old domains to new ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google's systems treat new gTLDs like other gTLDs.

They even wrote a post on the subject a few weeks back to cover off all the misconceptions out there.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/googles-handling-of-new-top-level.html